# Creating PySpark data frame without any alterations in column names

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am creating tables using `SparkSQL` with below `CTAS` command.

```
CREATE TABLE TBL2
STORED AS ORC 
LOCATION "dbfs:/loc"  
TBLPROPERTIES("orc.compress" = "SNAPPY")
AS
SELECT Col1
       , ColNext2
       , ColNext3
       , ... 
FROM TBL1
```

After that, I am reading files underlying above newly created location (TBL2) using below `PySpark` code. However, the `data frame` below is getting created with all column names in `lowercase` only. Whereas the expected result is in `camel case` as I am doing with `CTAS` above.

```
df = spark.read.format('ORC') \
     .option('inferSchema',True) \
     .option('header',True) \
     .load('dbfs:/loc')

data_frame.show()
```

Actual output:

```
col1 colnext2 colnext3 ...
```

Expected Output:

```
Col1 ColNext2 ColNext2 ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In version 2.3 and earlier, when reading from a Parquet data source table, Spark always returns null for any column whose column names in Hive metastore schema and Parquet schema are in different letter cases, no matter whether `spark.sql.caseSensitive` is set to true or false. Since 2.4, when `spark.sql.caseSensitive` is set to false, Spark does case insensitive column name resolution between Hive metastore schema and Parquet schema, so even column names are in different letter cases, Spark returns corresponding column values. An exception is thrown if there is ambiguity, i.e. more than one Parquet column is matched. This change also applies to Parquet Hive tables when `spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet` is set to true.
[source](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.2/sql-migration-guide-upgrade.html)